# LibreOffice background colors

Tags: colors

Using Ubuntu 20.4LTS and changed the background color for a power point presentation and now all my office word documents and other saved files that were a white background to the page all are the new color I chose for a specific power point.  How can I reset all to the plain white page background?  Even the saved files need to be changed back.  When opening a new word page it comes up with a blank page in the new odd color and don't want that happening to everything.
Is there a "Master" setting for all this?

Answer (score 0):

Open LibreOffice Writer and change the following settings.

`Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> Application Colors --> Document Background --> Set to White or Automatic`

Most likely only the application background is set to a different color, but your saved documents don't inherit the background.